# Exposing local Docker containers on internet (There are two containers linked to each other).

Tags: mysql, docker, localhost, containers, phabricator

I have created two docker containers, One is mysql and other is phabricator both are linked and both are locally. I have bound mysql port to 0.0.0.0. Now I want to expose the phabricator to internet. so that everyone can use that. --net=host option does not work with links. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your phabricator container with -p setting which defines the port mapping- Let's say your container internally exposes port 8080, then you can define it like -p 8080:8080, which means that the port 8080 is also externally accessible (as long as your host is reachable from internet on port 8080 without interfering firewall).